# OpenCV and MATLAB gray scale values differ for the same image

Tags: matlab, opencv

In MATLAB, i read a color video , extract a certain frame and convert it to a gray scale image using the `rgb2gray` function.But when I load the same video with OpenCV2.3.1, extract the same frame and then convert it to gray scale it doesn't give the same gray scale values as MATLAB. Why is that?

This is the C++ code using OpenCV:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);    
cap.open("Human sperm evaluation_0.avi");    

Mat image;    
Mat gray(480,640,CV_8U);    

for(int i=0;i<513;i++)
{
    cap>>image;
    cvtColor(image,gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
}

for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
    {
        cout<<(int)gray.at<uchar>(i,j)<<' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the image in MATLAB of uint8 type or you convert it to double?

Answer (score 5):

First, all color images in OpenCV are BGR and not RGB so maybe one of the problems could be that OpenCV is making the transformation wrong. You should use BGR2GRAY. 
And second, If I remember well in matlab yo should specify which are the ranges of values in your image. You have to put between 0 and 255 for a gray image.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I get this problem too , in MATLAB documents i can found rgb2gray implementation and it was so easy as follow

```
gray_value = 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B
```

So i implement this algorithm in OpenCV as follow

```
cv::Mat rgb_image = imread("/what/ever/directory/that/was/optional.jpg" );

int nrows = rgb_image.rows;  // number of columns
int ncols = rgb_image.cols;  // number of rows

cv::Mat gray_image( nrows , ncols , CV_8UC1 ); // define one channel Mat with same size as rgb_image

for(int row = 0; row < rgb_image.rows ; row++)
{
    for(int col = 0 ; col < pic.cols ; col++)
    {

        //matlab algorithm for rgb2gray
        gray.at<unsigned char>( row , col ) =
                0.2989 * rgb_image.at<Vec3b>( row , col )[0]+
                0.5870 * rgb_image.at<Vec3b>( row , col )[1]+
                0.1140 * rgb_image.at<Vec3b>( row , col )[2];        
   }

}
```

and this code will give same result as matlab, and in OpenCV you can use below code to regenerate it:

```
cv::cvtColor( rgb_image , gray_image , CV_BGR2GRAY );  //BLUE+GREEN+RED
```

but if you use below code

```
cv::cvtColor( rgb_image , gray_image , CV_RGB2GRAY ); //RED+GREEN+BLUE
```

then this algorithm will be in reverse order as follows:

```
gray_value = 0.2989 * R->B + 0.5870 * G->G + 0.1140 * B->R
```

and the output not same as MATLAB output

---

### using cv::transform function

I found a handy and useful function in opencv named `cv::transform` that implement above things in easiest way . if we have three `Mat` matrix named `src` for source image and `gray` for destination Matrix and `m` is a matrix that affect a transportation to every channel. by this matrixs we can implement `CV_BGR2GRAY` and `CV_RGB2GRAY` as follows

1-CV_BGR2GRAY

```
Mat src, gray, m ;
src=imread(" ");
m=(Mat_<float>(1,3)<<0.1140,0.5870,0.2989);
cv::transform(src,       //src
              gray,      //dst
              m );       //mtx
```

output will like as follow image
[image]

2-CV_RGB2GRAY

```
Mat src, gray, m ;
src=imread(" ");
m=(Mat_<float>(1,3)<<0.2989,0.5870,0.1140);
cv::transform(src,       //src
              gray,      //dst
              m );       //mtx
```

and output is like as follow
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The OpenCV Reference Manual, Release 2.4.10.0, Page 283:
"Note that the default color format in OpenCV is often referred to as RGB but it is actually BGR (the bytes are reversed). So the first byte in a standard (24-bit) color image will be an 8-bit Blue component, the second byte will be Green, and the third byte will be Red."