# matlab and opencv grayscale image values differs

Tags: matlab, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenCV and MATLAB gray scale values differ for the same image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282421/opencv-and-matlab-gray-scale-values-differ-for-the-same-image)

In matlab, i read a color vedio , extract a certain frame and convert it to gray scale image using rgb2gray function.But when loading the same vedio to openCV2.3.1 and extracting the same frame then converting to gray scale it doesn't give the same gray scale values as matlab??? why??.this is the C++ code with openCV2.3.1
     VideoCapture cap(0);
     cap.open("Human sperm evaluation_0.avi"); 
    Mat image; Mat gray(480,640,CV_8U);

```
for(int i=0;i<513;i++)
{ 
   cap >> image; 
   cvtColor(image,gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
} 

for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{ 
    for(int j=0;j<20;j++) 
    { 
        cout<<(int)gray.at(i,j) << ' '; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. OpenCV uses BGR color format by default. In this case you should use CV_BGR2GRAY mode. Make sure you really have RGB when using CV_RGB2GRAY.
2. Converting from RGB to gray may differ from one implementation to another. There is a common mistake in image processing software not to compensate the gamma-correction of the current RGB color space before summing channels up with some coefficients. If you have small differences in OpenCV and Matlab results, this can be the issue.